# How to inject the EntityManager dynamically?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm writing a framework which need to link to a persistence unit provided by the user. Previously, the entity manager was injected using `@PersistenceContext` annotation, but that's a static way :

```
public class MyItemReader implements ItemReader {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="myPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    ...
}
```

Now, I want the assignment to be dynamic. So that no matter what the persistence unit name is, the entity manager associated still can be found. Here's my implementation :

```
public class MyItemReader implements ItemReader {

    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject @BatchProperty
    private String persistenceUnitName;

    @Override
    public void open(Serializable checkpoint) throws Exception {
        String path = "java:comp/env/" + persistenceUnitName;
        em = (EntityManager) InitialContext.doLookup(path);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

My implementation works in WildFly, but I'm not sure it works in other Java EE container. And I'm not sure it works when the initial context changed.

So, is my implementation a good approach ?

Comment: It's good, just be carefull that some containers has different jndi publish name, but you can bind the base jndi path to a @Resource property initialized with deployment descriptors

Answer (score -1):

Don't need to specify unitName in persistanceContext. Try below one ..

```
@PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }
```

It will work.

Thanks

Comment: If user has more than one PU, then which one will be chosen in this case ?

Comment: In that case, try giving the unit name as @PersistenceContext(unitName="${persistence.UnitName}") add persistence.UnitName in your properties. it will work.